# How to solve the linear differential equation: $\frac{dL}{da}=k(L_{\infty }-L)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

From Wikipedia, it is stated that von Bertalanffy's model can be written
as follows:

$L(a)=L_{\infty }(1-e^{-k(a-t_{0}})$

Where $a$ is age, $k$ is the growth coefficient, $t_{0}$ is the
theoretical age when size is zero, and $L_{\infty }$ is the asymptotic
size. It is the solution of the following linear differential equation:

$\frac{dL}{da}=k(L_{\infty }-L)$

The following are the steps I took when attempting to solve the
differential equation to see if I would arrive at the same equation:

By separation of variables:

$\frac{dL}{(L_{\infty }-L)}=kda$

$\int{\frac{dL}{(L_{\infty }-L)}}=\int{kda}$

$-\ln \vert L_{\infty }-L\vert =ka+c$

$\ln \vert L_{\infty }-L\vert =-ka-c$

$e^{-ka-c}=L_{\infty }-L$

$L=L_{\infty }-e^{-ka-c}$

I'm stuck at this point; if anyone can point me in the right direction,
it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to show that the solution to the differential equation  $\frac{dL}{da}=k(L_{\infty }-L)$  is given by the equation: $L(a)=L_{\infty }(1-e^{-k(a-t_{0}})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $t_0$ is the theoretical age when size is zero

Hence, find $c$ in terms of $L_{\infty}, k, t_0$, as you have an initial parameter ($L = 0$ as stated above). Then substitute back in to the solution function and you obtain the desired result.

Comment: Many thanks, much appreciated.